# Является ли в данном примере ITelephone интерфейсом?

Tags: c++, интерфейс

изучаю ооп.
В процессе обучения возникла сложность с интерфейсами

У меня есть три объекта:

```
class ITelephone {
public:
virtual void Call();
virtual void TerminateCall();
} 

class Xiaomi : ITelephone {
private: 
void CheckSpam() {...} 
public:
void Call() {...CheckSpam();...} 
void TerminateCall() {...} 
}

class iPhone : ITelephone {
private: 
public:
void Call() {...} 
void TerminateCall() {...} 
}
```

Объект ITelephone задаёт функционал, которым должен обладать любой телефон. Объект Xiaomi и объект iPhone реализуют объект ITelephone. У объекта Xiaomi есть проверка на спам в вызовах, а у объекта iPhone просто реализация методов Call и TerminateCall. Правильно ли я понимаю, что объект ITelephone в данном примере будет являться интерфейсом?

Comment: Объект и класс (либо интерфейс), это разные вещи. Да, в вашем ITelephone - это интерфейс (если сделать его методы чисто виртуальными, то совсем кошерно-интерфейсно будет). Класс - это спецификация, или описание по которой создаются объекты. Интерфейс - это часть общей спецификации, отвечающая за конкретную часть поведения будущих объектов. Это такой поведенческий признак

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас нет трех [объектов](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object). У вас есть три [класса](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class).
2. Да, класс `ITelephone` в данном контексте - интерфейс.

Comment: Но разве в ооп нет правила, что всё является объектом?